# Java, how to get a collection of byte from a byte array

Tags: java, byte, arrays

This question may seems unique but I am having difficulties on solving it.

I have a byte array (a DW per row) and trying to get the byte value for every 9 bytes.
Here is how the byte array looks like:

```
0   1   2   3
4   5   6   7
8|  9   10  11
12  13  14  15
16  17| 18  19
20  21  22  23
24  25  26| 27
28  29  30  31
32  33  34  35|
.......
```

Here is a defined function that I need to use to get the value from the above patent:

```
getValue(int DWOffset, int highBit, int lowBit)

//DWOffset indicates the row of the data.
//highBit indicates the ending bit
//lowBit indicates the starting bit
```

My question is how to get every 9 bytes from the data (where the | appears) by using for loop? The data length can be found out by using

```
data.getLength();    //which returns the total number of bytes in the data
```

So far, I can get value on the first two row:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.getLength()/(4*2); i++){
    getValue(i*2, 31, 0);         //DW i
    getValue(i*2 + 1, 31, 0);     //DW i+1
}
```

Comment: Not clear at all. What's a DW? What does this data represent? Can you explain in more detail the `getValue()` API that you are supposed to use? Or provide a link to some documentation? Those inline comments don't help much. Do you want to get one byte from each group of nine bytes? Or get all the bytes, in chunks of nine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you seem to be mixing paradigms, conceptually looking at it as both a 2-dimensional and a 1-dimensional array.  Looking at it as 2-dimensional, you need a getValue(int row, int column) that returns a single byte.  Then you can do something like this:

```
final int TOTAL_BYTES_TO_INCLUDE = 9;

byte[] byteArray[] = new byte[TOTAL_BYTES_TO_INCLUDE];
int arrayIndex = 0;


for (int r = 0; r++; r < number_of_rows) {
  for (int c = 0; c++; c < 4) {
     byteArray[arrayIndex++] = getValue(r, c);
     if (arrayIndex >= TOTAL_BYTES_TO_INCLUDE) {
        ... do something with your byte array ...
        arrayIndex = 0;
     }
   }
}
```

There's some corner cases to deal with, like what happens if the number of available values is not a multiple of 9, what happens.  What happens if the value read in causes byte-overflow.  I don't reinitialize the array before each iteration, but is there any risk to something being left behind.